# Mix Shader Confusion

Tags: texturing

I am using the mix shader node for detailing a tower (cylinder) and have encountered an issue. The idea is that the main texture is white brick, with a black silhouette overlaid. I am using an Image Texture for the silhouette, putting the brick and image through the mix shader node. However, I can't get the black silhouette to work properly. I created one that is the opposite (black brick with white silhouette) and it worked fine. But when I try to balance the image of the black silhouette with the white brick, the silhouette doesn't show up until the entire thing is too dark. Both silhouette images have transparent backgrounds, so that shouldn't be an issue, but I can't seem to get the black one to mix with the white brick cleanly like the white one did. I'm still learning the details of this kind of detailing, so I may be overlooking an option.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add images of your current nodes and the textures you have.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your nodes, but a hackish fix could be to set it up the way it works, and then invert it.